# LTSpice library Voltage Controlled Switch SW returns error: Unknown parameter "sw". Why?

Tags: ltspice, error, model

I'm having problems with the LTSpice Voltage controlled switch in a very simple circuit:

A pulsed voltage source is used to switch MYSW on and off: PULSE(0 5 15m 1n 1n 0.15m 16m 1) .

The voltage Controlled Switch is associated with .model MYSW SW(Ron=1m Roff=10Meg Vt=3 Vh=0.0 Lser=1p Vser=0.0), with the switch's Spice model attribute set to MYSW.

The intention is to switch a current from a DC voltage source through a 1k resistor.

When I run the sim I get the following error message:

```
Error on line 5 : s1 n001 0 n002 0 mysw sw
     Unknown parameter "sw"
Direct Newton iteration for .op point succeeded.

Date: Wed Mar 29 12:28:07 2023
Total elapsed time: 0.038 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = modified trap
totiter = 2473
traniter = 2470
tranpoints = 1236
accept = 1207
rejected = 29
matrix size = 5
fillins = 0
solver = Alternate
Matrix Compiler1: 108 bytes object code size  0.0/0.0/[0.0]
Matrix Compiler2: off  [0.0]/0.1/0.0
```

Can anyone please explain what this error is all about and how I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the `SpiceModel` attribute, set the `Value` attribute to `MYSW`.

[image]